# Replacing 2 LP Gas Water Heaters

Tags: water-heater

We just bought a 22 year old Log Cabin this past summer in the Wasatch Mountains. It's very large (> 7,000 sf, 5 bathrooms). Now we have > 4' of snow on the ground, and repair issues have begun emerging!

Yesterday our 40 gallon tank "upstream" unit of two LP gas tank water heaters (connected in series in the furnace room) started dripping water quickly and pooling on the floor. Hot water is still available from the downstream unit, as long as I tolerate the continuous water leaking from the upstream unit (manageable for now thanks to a concrete floor & floor drain). I don't know how hard our water is here, but it comes from the city of Springville, UT from a reservoir a little higher up Hobble Creek canyon (spring fed).

Here are several variables I'm considering to arrive at a better/ more optimal solution:

1. We're on LP for all our heating (via two 1,000 gallon LP tanks). Propane is very expensive now ($2.09/ gallon at last refill) and we go thru a LOT of it, especially this time of year! On the other hand, electricity rates are incredibly cheap here, only ~ $0.115/ kWh incl. taxes & delivery charges. (We moved here from So Cal, where the average rate was 3X higher, at ~ $0.35 per kWh !)
2. We had a tankless gas WH for the last 20 years in So Cal (3,000 sf home w/ 4 baths), and we really liked it. So, my initial decision matrix had 2 variables 1.) Keeping LP Gas for the new replacement tank, vs replacing it w/an Electric unit, and 2.) a traditional Tank design again, vs a Tankless unit. (Note, space is NOT at a premium now, the furnace room is a spacious 11' x 14' and not crowded).
3. Then I researched an electric **hybrid heat pump** (tank) WH, which qualifies for a much higher 30% tax credit limit (ie $2,000 vs only $600 cap), and is super efficient. So suddenly we had new, unfamiliar solution to consider.
4. Then I thought of a few MORE possible solutions:
   A. Just bypass & remove the (older, leaking) upstream tank WH, and let the (newer, slightly
   larger) WH handle the whole house temporarily. (There are only 2 of us living here!)

   Then, if/when it can't keep up demand-wise (especially when we have visitors), install
   a 2nd, tankless WH dedicated to handle just maybe the laundry room & master bath (etc),
   closer to the demand. (Today it takes forever to get hot water today in the master bath,
   located very far and 3 floors away from the existing 2 WH's, w. no recirc. pump loop. In
   fact, the MBR is over the garage, so we get 45 ice degree cold drinking water on tap!)

   Under this scenario, the original downstream tank WH in the furnace room could still
   supply the other 4 baths (2 of which are almost never used, at least currently).

   B. Leave the downstream unit (assumed 7 yrs old, working fine) alone, but just replace the
   failing upstream unit with a new electric heat-pump WH (50 or 80 gallon?).
   When the downstream unit eventually fails in a few years, maybe remove it and install a
   2nd, tankless WH in the garage then, to supply the MBR and maybe another room.

Based on what I've indicated so far, any suggestions which route above (or other ideas) what we should do?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. If you find that difficult it may be because your question is actually too broad. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: At the prices you mentioned, propane is still cheaper than electric. Propane is costing $22.88 per million BTU, electric is $33.20. An electric resistance water heater is virtually 100% efficient, but a propane condensing water heater at 93% still costs only $24.60, and a clunky old hot-flue propane water heater at 80% still costs only $28.60 per million BTU delivered to the water. So add this to your decision matrix.

Comment: 4A makes the most sense immediately. Not being in a rush or dealing with active leaks makes for a calmer shopping process. Your incredibly cheap electricity is about equal to $3/gallon propane, for a reality check, unless you do get a heat pump involved.

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with the electric hybrid heat pump water heater. It could be a great fit in a place where ambient heat is free, but you live in a place that is very heating-dominant. I'll be surprised if you run air conditioning more than two hours daily in the peak of summer (two months, maybe three out of the whole year). The heat pump water heater has to be inside your house to protect it from freezing in the winter; this means it's pumping heat *out* of the furnace room *into* the water -- and your furnace is having to replace that heat. When you think of the house as a complete system, the stellar component-level efficiency of the heat pump water heater doesn't look so great.

Next you can consider "how much hot water do we need?" If the one tank heater provides enough for a single use-period, and then there's enough resting time for it to recover before the next use-period comes along, then great. Let it be.

If you conclude that you need more hot water than the one heater can provide then you really get into the details: How much GPM flow do we need? For how long? How much recovery time can we allow? The answers to these questions will guide you toward instant or tank style and LP or electric fuel.

Though electricity is cheap at your location, an *instant electric* water heater draws a very high current. You'll *at least* need new high-amp electric circuits installed to the heater's location, and it could even ripple into upgrading your main electric panel or even the service line. Considering your remote location and its implied long electric service line, such an upgrade could come at significant expense.

An instant water heater could be a nice upgrade, though, particularly considering the points of use that are far from the furnace room. An instant heater installed nearer to that part of the house would speed hot water delivery. It probably should use LP fuel though.

Replacing the failed LP tank heater with an electric tank heater would be a relatively easy thing. It too would require a new electric circuit, but with much smaller cable and smaller demand on your electric service, its total installation cost is much less likely to snowball.

Answer (score 1):

> Then I thought of a few MORE possible solutions: A. Just bypass & remove the (older, leaking) upstream tank WH, and let the (newer, slightly larger) WH handle the whole house temporarily. (There are only 2 of us living here!)

You know your usage, but that seems most sensible. The only reason to run two tanks in series is to increase run capacity.  Temporarily bypass it with a flex cable and see how it goes.

> Then I researched an electric hybrid heat pump (tank) WH, which qualifies for a much higher 30% tax credit limit (ie $2,000 vs only $600 cap), and is super efficient. So suddenly we had new, unfamiliar solution to consider.

Heat pumps do not create heat. They move it.

The simplest "heat pump water heaters" simply steal heat from the utility room, meaning either your utility room turns into a freezer, or you must run the house heat harder to compensate.  You might need to put a mini-split heat pump in the utility room so you can pump heat from outside and pump it again into the water!  Wouldn't it be nice to do that in one step?

Multi-head mini-split systems are becoming ever more popular (in the US. They've always been popular overseas).  While most heads are simply high-on-wall units to provide HVAC, I foresee heads for mini-splits which are tanked water heaters, and simply route their refrigerant back to the outdoor unit. These split "heat pump water heaters" make sense since they are taking heat from outside - heck in summer they're nearly pumping heat downhill, which is exceedingly efficient!

> Then, if/when it can't keep up demand-wise (especially when we have visitors), install a 2nd, tankless WH dedicated to handle just maybe the laundry room & master bath (etc), closer to the demand.

The one-way path to true stupidity is having tanked and tankless heaters both serving the same faucet. That does not work (or rather, doesn't do anything worth doing).

But that aside, it makes perfect sense to have a tank serve some outlets and a tankless serve completely different outlets. If you can get the exhaust stack for a gas tankless, have at. Otherwise you need to think carefully about demand.

> Today it takes forever to get hot water today in the master bath, located very far and 3 floors away from the existing 2 WH's, w. no recirc. pump loop.

That certainly is a problem worth fixing. Depending on how much electricity you can get, you might use "near-point-of-use" electric tankless heaters like the British do - they use 35-45 amp (8,500-10,500 watt) water heaters *directly at the showerhead* and they work like a champ. (At water flow rates somewhat low by American standards.  That's not *that big* of a tankless heater. . The bathroom sink could be tapped off the shower in that bathroom, staying consistent with the "don't use the sink hot water while I'm taking a shower" wisdom we all know.

Here's what not to do: Decide to go electric tankless with **One Heater To Rule Them All** installed in the original tank location - you still have the 45 second wait to get hot water in the distant outlets, but you also have a 150-200A load you are slapping on the system! Dumb, dumb, dumb.

And for instance in laundry room, that can be quite a small tankless because you can just insert a flow restrictor to slow it down to say 0.4 GPM - then a tiny 4000W tankless can keep up.   That's only 20A. The washing machine doesn't give a care, it'll wait 5 more minutes to fill.  Or for that matter, they make washing machines with onboard heaters that simply take cold water.  If the slop sink in the laundry room is in frequent use, people might find that annoying.

> B. Leave the downstream unit (assumed 7 yrs old, working fine) alone, but just replace the failing upstream unit with a new electric heat-pump WH (50 or 80 gallon?)

Only if you can get it to interchange air from outside the building IMO.

> and install a 2nd, tankless WH in the garage then, to supply the MBR and maybe another room

As long as it's mutually exclusive and isn't in series or parallel with a tanked heater.  Having a tankless only to avoid the 45 second wait doesn't work, because if the tankless was big enough to matter for 45 seconds, it's big enough to matter at all times.  *And **if it's not** big enough to serve the needs at all times, then it won't work for 45 seconds either... and you're right back to square one with having to run the water and wait*.

I suppose one might have a hybrid circulating system where you circulate water at 80F (which will have very little thermal loss to a 70F-maintained house) and then your electric tankless only needs to lift water from 80F to 110F, which will require far less power - and now the power needs are achievable.  Just try not to breed legionella!

Answer (score 1):

### At those prices, propane is cheaper, still.

In the near term, cutting out the leaking heater is the obvious immediate correct decision.

Propane - 91,500 BTU/gallon X efficiency of the thing burning it - 80-95% is a typical range. the other 5-20% is thrown away as waste heat going outside.

Electricity - 3412 BTU/kWh, (resistive heat) or X the COP of the heat pump unit using it. In the Wasatch, you'd really want a ground source unit.

So, $1 spent on propane at $2.09/gallon buys you 43,780 BTU before you actually use it, and when you burn it in a 95% efficient heater, you get to keep 41591 BTU in the house. In an 80% efficient heater you get to keep 35,024 BTU for your dollar of propane.

$1 spent on $0.115/kWh electricity gets you 29,670 BTU and you get to keep all of it, if used in a resistive heat application such as "instant" hot water, conventional water heater, or a toaster. Only if you can make use of a heat pump to multiply the energy in, by moving heat from elsewhere does it beat propane at your current prices. If elsewhere is inside your house (as for the common hybrid heat pump waterheaters) you'll burn more propane to make up for it.

A ground source heat pump qualifies for large tax breaks if you like those, and consistently opereates around a COP of 3 or 4, so you get something in the ballpark of 89,000-118,000 BTU for your dollar of electricity. A cold climate air source can do that well, but drops to a COP of 2 or even 1 when it's pushed to its low temperature extremes. Once you get to 1, you might as well turn on a toaster. But when not at the extremes, it wins quite handily. You only need a COP of 1.18 to equal an 80% efficient propane burner at your current prices, or 1.4 to equal a 95% efficient propane burner.

You may also be able to alter the math in your favor for electric use by adding solar panels and reducing your electricity cost - my friends in that area typically have an excess from their installation, so they only pay the connection fee.

As for the generally high heating bill/propane use, you either pay to heat 7000 square feet you are not really using a lot of, or you close rooms off and heat them much less than the rooms you actually use. Can't do much to insulate a log cabin better unless you give up the log cabin look on one side of the walls, but you can close doors and turn down heat (changing the system to allow that zoning if it does not right now) in unused areas, rather than paying to heat them. That's fairly standard for large houses with more summer occupants than winter occupants, historically. If you get influxes of winter visitors, you turn the heat up before they arraive, and down when they leave. You can also check over the chinking (sealant between logs), and fix it if it's in need of fixing.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your pricing changes on propane. How is the price to heat at (a mythical) 100% efficiency _higher_ than it is to heat at a realistic 95%? Wouldn't it cost _more_ to heat at a lower efficiency since some of the heat is going up the chimney instead of into the water, therefore using more gas to get the same thermal rise in the water?

Comment: Makes much more sense now! I could _feel_ where you were headed, but just couldn't wrap my brain around it before.